# terraform example for Latency based route53 (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

Do anyone have an example for latency based route53 (AWS) recordset using terraform?

I want to know all the attributes I can pass including evaluate target health-check for alias records.

Comment: What are you missing from [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id}"
  name    = "example.com"
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = "${aws_elb.main.dns_name}"
    zone_id                = "${aws_elb.main.zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }

  latency_routing_policy {
    region = ${var.region}
  }
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html#latency_routing_policy

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-latency